# Javascript Toggle in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

```
function globalModelToggleClicked(modname)
{
 var state = this.checked ? true : false;
 var display = this.checked ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var input_l = inputs.length;

 // check uncheck inputs checkboxes
 while(input_l--)
 {
   var input = inputs[input_l];
   if(input.getAttribute('class') == modname)
   {
     input.checked = state;
   }
 }

 // show/ hide all colorings
 var main = document.getElementById('main');
 var divs = main.getElementsByTagName('div');
 var divs_l = divs.length;
 var regex = new RegExp(modname);

 while(divs_l--)
 {
   var div = divs[divs_l];
   if( regex.test(div.getAttribute('class')) 
    && ( /hit/.test(div.getAttribute('class'))
         || /seqBorder/.test(div.getAttribute('class')) 
       )
     )
   {
     div.style.display = display;
   }
 }
}




function localModelToggleClicked(modname)
{

  var display = this.checked ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
  // get parent fieldset
  var fieldset = this.parentNode;
  while(fieldset.nodeName != 'FIELDSET')
  {
    fieldset = fieldset.parentNode;
  }

  // show/ hide all colorings
  var divs = fieldset.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var divs_l = divs.length;
  var regex = new RegExp(modname);


  while(divs_l--)
  {
    var div = divs[divs_l];
    if( regex.test(div.getAttribute('class'))
    && ( /hit/.test(div.getAttribute('class'))
         || /seqBorder/.test(div.getAttribute('class'))
       )
      )
    {
        div.style.display = display;
    }
 }
}
```

The two above functions toggle the div's visibility.  They work perfectly in all browsers except IE(8) and I have no idea what is wrong.  I have tried the debugger, which shows nothing.  The functions are on an external script with other functions, which are working.  When I alert inside the function everything seems in order.  Can anyone help
?

Comment: Are Javascript libraries such as jQuery out of the question here? This could be written in a couple of lines of code with jQuery and you're far less likely to hit browser incompatibilities.

Comment: I intially done this in Jquery, and it was a similar problem, so i coded in javascript which seemed to fix the problem at first, but nope, Internet Explorer does not like the code.:(

Comment: Could you explain how the functions are intended to be used? A jsFiddle demo would be cool, too.

Comment: I have to chime in with White Elephant. You are spending so much time writing code that with jQuery could be done in a few lines. I would hate to be the next developer given the job of maintaining your code. Could you at least write more generic functions than one-use specific functions that only do a particular thing? Look, you have two functions that toggle stuff... write a toggling function that works for both. Your code is looking a bit like spaghetti.

Comment: I am not a developer, nor am I a programmer.  I am a scientist trying to learn a new discipline to help with me with my work.  I have done the above in Jquery in very few lines with ease, which worked perfectly, except when it was put on a server, so i had to remove it as for no explainable reason it wont work.The above code, are two separate toggling functions.Both Toggle in Completely Different ways, and will be used in other tools separately like this for a reason.  I agree with you on Jquery, but the rest I dnt Agree. Thanks For the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with the `getAttribute('class')` apparently IE does not accept this.  So i use the `className` instead.  Which works perfectly in all browsers.